# What is the origin of the phrase "racing cert"?

Tags: etymology, terminology

I had encountered the phrase, “racing cert”, the other day, and I had to go look it up. The only definition I immediately found was [one from UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Racing%20cert):

> English colloquialism. Born from gambling talk and used to indicate a statistical or logical outcome that appears to be a foregone conclusion.

It seems to be mostly related to horse racing, and used even in news articles as a jargon term (e.g. [“Racing cert: The 400-year history of Perth racecourse”](http://www.scotsman.com/lifestyle/heritage/racing-cert-the-400-year-history-of-perth-racecourse-1-2255563)), but I had found no confirmation of that definition, nor explanation whence it came from exactly. If it has anything to do with so-called “racing certificates”, I could not even find meaningful explanation as to what that is, especially pertaining to horse racing. In other racing (auto, or sailing, for instance) it appears to be a sort of manifest clearing the participant (car or a boat) for the race after inspection, and for animals it also seemed to include veterinary check up. But I fail to grip how does that imply the “foregone conclusion”.

*Note.* As of this note, I picked a winner, although I thought all three answers were very helpful in understanding, and I upvoted them all. There are some question still unanswered (When did the meaning of this phrase went from ironic to literal? Are there any other examples of usage of “racing certainty” around 1834 St. Leger Stakes?), and if others add or improve their answers, I might reconsider. but generally, good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Racing cert* is from *racing certainty* and was once used literally when talking about horse racing but has since changed so it can be used to describe any (particularly sporting) *dead cert*.

### Racing certainty

I found an antedating to the OED's 1859 of *racing certainty*, in *[The Monthly Magazine, Or, British Register, Volume XXIV](http://books.google.fi/books?id=5rcRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA354&dq=%22racing%20cert%22%20OR%20%22racing%20certainty%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=otEGUai0G-3E4gSA7YHgAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22racing%20certainty%22&f=false)* of October 1837:

[image: If ever there was a racing certainty, it was that, barring accidents, he must win the Leger. He was well, and on the Thursday, at Tattersall's, the last betting day previous to the race, backed at even with the field, when a commission arrived from a ...]

This is talking about horse racing.

### Racing cert

*Racing cert* doesn't show up in print until much later, but that doesn't mean people hadn't already been using it in speech for some time. The earliest I found was in a 1920 snippet of *[St. George's Gazette, Volume 38](http://books.google.fi/books?id=pq0aAQAAMAAJ&q=%22racing%20cert%22&dq=%22racing%20cert%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=09IGUejtJ7CM4gTFmoDIBQ&redir_esc=y)* (Great Britain. Army. Northumberland Fusiliers):

[image: On the 8th instant our first match against Washington resulted in a goalless draw after a strenuous game at Washington, and it seemed a "racing cert" on the game at home the following Wednesday, but we also ran, to the tune of being beaten by two goals to nil, our Washington visitors well deserving to win.]

> On the 8th instant our first match against Washington resulted in a goalless draw after a strenuous game at Washington, and it seemed a "racing cert" on the game at home the following Wednesday, but we also ran, to the tune of being beaten by two goals to nil, our Washington visitors well deserving to win.

This is still sport, although rather than being used literally (about horse racing) it's changed to being used figuratively (about football).

Comment: I'm not sure I'd consider that an antecedent of the expression, but rather a straightforward noun adjunct - they're talking about racing, and within that context say "if ever there was a certainty". In particular, they are talking about something that didn't happen (in other words, they share my objection to the very concept of "racing certainty"). +1 for an interesting find all the same though,

Comment: @JonHanna, I think it could be really significant, because the horse [indeed had lost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plenipotentiary_(horse)) that race, and the controversy ensued. I wonder if there are sources surrounding that 1834 St. Leger Stakes that indeed proclaimed the “racing certainty” which did not materialize.

Comment: The first Barry found was also sarcastic, so we can perhaps see the shape of the word's growth - first as a sarcastic use (and a more sensible one, considering that the whole point of racing is its unpredictability) that at some point got inverted into a straight use. I'm now very curious myself as to when that inversion happened.

Comment: @JonHanna, should we, mayhaps, start another question about that switch?

Comment: @Hugo, technical question: how were you able to quote from the _Gazette_? For me it showed up as a tiny, fuzzy image, totally illegible.

Comment: @theUg: For me, the image is small but just about legible. I've put a screenshot in the answer. But I copied and pasted the text from the [search summary](https://www.google.fi/search?q=%22racing+cert%22&hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=ZWgHUdvpJqiN4gTP34CIDw&ved=0CCMQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1920%2Ccd_max%3A1920&tbm=bks). / Interesting the horse Plenipotentiary is famous enough today to warrant a [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plenipotentiary_(horse)), and that it mentions this loss in the first paragraph.

Comment: I did [note](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101961/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-racing-cert/101980#comment207389_101980) the significance of this loss earlier.

Comment: @theUg: The entry for *cert* in John S. Farmer's *[A Dictionary of slang and Colloquial English](http://books.google.fi/books?id=lUYVAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA477&dq=%22racing+cert%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2WgHUdbnMtT54QSb-4DQAg&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAw#v=snippet&q=certainty&f=false)* (1927) is: *A certainty: also a dead (or moral) certainty, a dead 'un, and a moral (1859).*

Answer (score 2):

*Cert* has been a slang abbreviation for *certainty* for a long time (1889 according to etymonline.com, which may or may not be true, but *cert* and *dead cert* are definitely not very recent).

*Cert* and *dead cert* are particularly popular among gamblers, who will often tell you with great conviction that they know of a cert in a given race or sporting event.

Meanwhile, *racing certainty* from the same demographic, exists both literally (if not reliably) of racehorses, and figuratively about other things.

*Racing cert* combines that phrase and that abbreviation. If somebody says something is a racing cert, they are sure it will be true, will come to pass, etc.

(That said, if when an actual racehorse is described as a racing cert, take that information with a grain of salt).

Comment: Sounds a good explanation, but more sources would be welcome. Another thing is that Google n-grams do not find any. I understand it is colloquial, but it would be reflected in fiction. “Dead cert”, on the contrary seems to be [continuously used](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Dead+cert+%2B+dead+cert&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) since late XIX century.

Comment: The earliest quote for "racing certainty" at http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/racing-certainty is a book published in 1993, and certainly while I've known "cert" and "dead cert" since childhood, I've only heard "racing certainty" recently (and it's a phrase that always itches me, since to my mind "racing certainty" is an oxymoron). I'm guessing it is indeed quite recent, though the abbreviation to "racing cert" is not surprising.

Comment: [According to n-grams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=racing+certainty&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), “racing certainty” was used earlier, and ironically as well ([from 1921](http://books.google.com/books?id=MUbWP2fx7zAC&q=%22racing+certainty%22&dq=%22racing+certainty%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=KsUGUa2ACs_higKUqIGIDw&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCQ): “Was he devoted to Anglo-Saxondom because it was a greater ego or because it was the ideal type of a God whose existence was at best a ‘racing certainty’?”)

Comment: I suppose some of this could be incorporated in the answer and we would have a winner.

Comment: The OED's earliest citation is from 1859: _All other ‘certainties’ we have a thorough distrust of, more especially of racing ‘certainties’_.

Comment: Ah, but what I want to know now, is when did that ironic use (which makes a lot more sense) become straight?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit from the OED entry for **racing certainty**

> *n. Brit.* A horse considered certain to win a race; (in extended use) anything regarded as certain to happen; a ‘sure thing’.
>   1859   Era 2 Oct. 3/4   All other ‘certainties’ we have a thorough distrust of, more especially of racing ‘certainties’.

And for **cert** *Abbrev. of certain adj., certainty*

> *n. slang* A certainty (esp. in phr. a dead cert ); spec. in horse-racing, a horse that is considered certain to win.
>   1889 Man of the World 29 June 3/2   Love-in-Idleness is bound to take the Rous Memorial, and I hear Pioneer is a cert. for the St. James's.

And [here's](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=racing%20cert,dead%20cert&year_start=1870&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) a chart to show that *dead cert* has always been far more common...

[image]

Comment: Comparing to [“racing certainty”](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=racing+certainty%2Cdead+cert&year_start=1870&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) produces slightly smaller margin, but what surprises me is that for a hundred years no one (not enough, anyhow) thought of contracting _certainty_ to _cert_ in that phrase, given how ubiquitous _cert_ seems to have been.

Comment: @theUg: Well, I use both the *dead* and the *racing* varieties. In descending order of frequency, probably *dead cert, racing certainty, racing cert, dead certainty*. I never use just *cert* on its own, but I'm quite likely to say something *is a certainty*. I think my usage just reflects the average of what I encounter in others.

Comment: Perhaps the abbreviated *cert* was used often enough in racing that there was simply no need to specify it as a *racing cert*. Perhaps that's was only needed when it was applied figuratively outside of racing to other sports and things.